# Schema design for users with many school classes

Tags: mysql, sqlite, eloquent, schema

I am trying to add a new table called `user_classes` which will associate my user's classes. I am building a website that allows them to generate class schedues. Within my database, I have two existing tables - a `users` table which contains the `id`, `name`, and `email`:

```
=users table=                                                            
id    name    email                                                       
1     John    john@example.com
```

I also have a `classes` table which contains all my classes. `crn` is simply the course number, and name is the name of the class.

```
=classes table=                                                              
id    crn    name                                                              
1     4000   CS 101                                                             
2     4001   CS 102                                                             
3     4003   CS 103
```

This new table is what I am thinking. I have an `id` which is the PK, have an `user_id` column to say that `John Doe` has all the following `crn`s.

```
=user_classes table=                                                         
id    user_id   crn                                                       
1     1         4000                                                      
2     1         4001                                                      
3     1         4003
```

My question is, is the `user_classes` a good design? Instead of `crn`, should I use the `id` from classes instead?

In this schema, user has many classes. However, a class also has many users.

Comment: Just use `class_id` and `user_id` in your new table

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought too.

Comment: So simply have `user_id` and `class_id`?

Comment: Exactly. And make these 2 columns the key of your table

Comment: `And make these 2 columns the key of your table ` do you mind clarifying this?

Comment: If you also put a unique key on these 2 columns then you can't have duplicate entries in there.

Comment: Well either way, these 2 columns should be unique, but if you lose the surrogate id then they should be PRIMARY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the 2 columns to your classes and users

```
create table user_classes 
(
  user_id int, class_id int,
  foreign key (user_id) references users(id),
  foreign key (class_id) references classes(id),
  unique (user_id, class_id)
);
```

If you then for instance need to select all users of a class named 'math' you can do

```
select u.*
from users u
join user_classes uc on uc.user_id = u.id
join classes c on uc.class_id = c.id
where c.name = 'math'
```